# JQuery UI Menu Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the native jquery ui menu and trying to get it to scroll.  I found that it actually has this behavior built in (sort of).  I'm not sure if it's intentional or not.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/rn4rB/)

```
/////////////////////////////////// HTML ////////////////////////////////////////////

<div id="container">
    <ul id="menu">
        <div id="scrollup">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
        </div>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
        <div id="scrolldown">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

/////////////////////////////////// CSS ////////////////////////////////////////////

#container {
    height: 350px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#menu {
    max-height: 75%;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
}

#menu #scrollup,
#menu #scrolldown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 113px;
}

#menu #scrolldown {
    top: 311px;
}


/////////////////////////////////// JQUERY //////////////////////////////////////////

$('#menu').menu().removeClass('ui-menu-icons');
```

This is the best I can come up, and I'm not really happy with it.  I've had to increase the top and bottom padding to allow for a larger scroll-able area.  This itself isn't terrible but not ideal.  My biggest concern is showing my users that this list is scroll-able.  I've hacked in some display arrows using the jquery ui icons, but it doesn't quite feel right.  By putting them on the right they mimic a scrollbar, but you can't click on them.

Ideally what I'd like is for the arrows to be centered, but when you hover them the list is still scroll-able.  By using a span I can achieve the positioning but then the text is visible underneath and just looks bad.  By using a div it looks cleaner, but then the entire area isn't scroll-able.

I'm looking for a better, cleaner, and more intuitive way to implement this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is scrolling on the side, no js here though obviously

```
 #menu {
          overflow-y: scroll;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          height: 200px;
          width: 200px;
        } 

  <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: didn't think of something so simple.  It doesn't use the native mouseoever controls but this could be the most simple and elegant solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on MAC as the Overflow-y scroll seems to be always considered as Visible if there's enough space to the Right of the menu

also, if the menu has a submenu, its width has to be inside the scrollbar