# How to make sub-menus scrollable

Tags: css, submenu, horizontal-scrolling

I've got at least one sub-menu that is very long and another well on its way. It looks fine on desktop and mobile but I'd like to make these sub-menus scrollable so that it's not too long and/or overwhelms people.

I'm not at JavaScript yet so I need a simple CSS trick that will work. The closest I've come to is located here:

[Scrolling Submenus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206692/scrolling-submenus-in-jquery-ui-menu)

but it bunches everything up and only the last menu item appears. I've tried making it longer but nothing seems to work.

## CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  width: 185px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

Any suggestions?

[partyfavorz.com](https://partyfavorz.com)

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set a height to your List and overflow-y:

```
.dropdown-menu {
     height: 500px; // change it as you like
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: no problem! I saw you did the change live! I think instead of height: 500px just do max-height: 500px. so the other menus height will fit to the content if it's smaller then 500px

Comment: but if i have another sub menu inside .dropdown-menu it won't show because of overflow

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the div vertically scrollable, you need to have a parent of a smaller height than the div that is being scrolled.

```
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
}
```

You can see the example on the link https://jsfiddle.net/sebdum/npz8u6x2/1/